# Find Probability of Losing The Tags

Tags: probability

Tags are attached to the left and right hind legs of a cow in a pasture. Let A1 be the
event that the left leg tag is lost and A2 the event that the right leg tag is lost. Suppose
these two events are independent and P(A1) = P(A2) = 0.3

a. Find the probability that at least one leg tag is lost.

b. Find the probability that exactly one tag is lost, given that at least one tag is lost.

c. Find the probability that exactly one tag is lost, given that at most one tag is lost.

My Work: a) We need to find (P(A1) OR P(A2)) = 0.3 + 0.3 - 0.09 = 0.51 (final answer)

(P(A1) AND P(A2)) = 0.3 x 0.3 (As they are independent) = 0.09 so that's where the 0.09 comes from.

b) So the key word is Exactly one, given that AT LEAST one tag has been lost. Seeing as we don't know what tag is lost, I did 0.51 - 0.09 = 0.42 (Which the probability of losing ONLY one tag). So this is case where one tag is already lost. Now we do the case where two tags have already been lost which I believe is just 0 as there are only two tags on the cow to begin with so it can't lose anymore so P = 0. Therefore 0.42 + 0 = 0.42 which is the final probability

c) The key word here is again Exactly one, given that AT MOST one tag is lost. So case 1: no tags have been lost. Then it's just 0.42 as that's the probability of losing ONLY one tag. Case 2: one tag has been lost already, then again I believe it's just 0.42 as you don't know what tag has been lost and that's the probability of losing only one Tag. so the final probability is 0.42 + 0.42 = 0.84

My gut instinct is telling me i'm overthinking it.

Should b) just be 0.3? (The probability of losing one tag) and should c) just be 0.42 + 0.3 = 0.72?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset all mathematical expression (including numbers).  It will make your posts more readable, and you'll get a better response.

Comment: Perhaps it would clarify things for you if you took actual numbers.  Say there were $100$ cows.  Then there are $21$ cows that lost just their left tag, $21$ that lost just their right, $9$ that lost both, and $49$ that lost neither.  Can you work out the problem in that setting?

Comment: The word "given" in b and c indicates conditional probability.